# WHERE on View Alias Causes Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a view like this:

```
SELECT location, CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) AS ProcessCode
FROM   dbo.asset
WHERE  (status NOT IN ('INACTIVE', 'NOT READY', 'LIMITEDUSE'))
AND (location LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_')
```

If I call it like this, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM FooView
```

However, if I add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM FooView WHERE ProcessCode > 0
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '-01-' to data
>   type int.

Why? Since location must be in the format `1-2-100-0800-A`, I don't see how there can be a conversion error. Is it possible that the `CAST` fails before the `WHERE` has a chance to filter the results? If so, then why does the first query work?

**EDIT - WORK-AROUND**

I just had a co-worker suggest a good work-around. It works, but it still doesn't explain why the initial problem.

This is in the SELECT for ProcessCode:

```
CASE WHEN location LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_'
THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) ELSE 0 END AS ProcessCode,
```

Comment: out of interest which version of sql server? and what column type is Location?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Location is varchar(24).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your view to this

```
SELECT location,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) > ''
             AND SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
                 CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) END AS ProcessCode
  FROM dbo.asset
 WHERE (status NOT IN ('INACTIVE', 'NOT READY', 'LIMITEDUSE'))
   AND (location LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_')
```

See this [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

SQL Server is free to evaluate the WHERE/SELECT clause in the order that it decides is optimized.  A view unless materialized as an INDEXED VIEW is expanded to the outer query, so your WHERE clause is actually being streamlined into the view, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM FooView WHERE ProcessCode > 0
 -- is really seen as
SELECT location, CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) AS ProcessCode
FROM   dbo.asset
WHERE  (status NOT IN ('INACTIVE', 'NOT READY', 'LIMITEDUSE'))
AND (location LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_')
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) > 0 ---- << Expanded inline
```

Because the expression is used both for the SELECT and WHERE clauses, it seems SQL Server has decided to resolve the expression in the SELECT clause first in the original retrieval. This can easily be seen by using Ctrl-L to view the query execution plan.  You will see that SQL Server makes a single retrieval from the table, taking 2 expressions, being `location` and `CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int)` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat like the work-around in my question. See my edit. While it provides a working alternative, it doesn't explain the original behavior.

Comment: I have added an explanation. Also, your workaround is somewhat data-dependent because you're not testing the bit that's being casted but rather the pattern of the column data.

Comment: That would explain the behavior. If the SELECT is being evaluated before the WHERE has had a chance to filter the bad data, that would cause the error. Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 1):

This works on Sql Server 2008, something else funky is going on...

```
create view myview
AS
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING('1-2-100-0800-A', 9, 4) AS int) as ProcessCode
Where '1-2-100-0800-A' LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_'

GO

SELECT * FROM myview WHERE ProcessCode > 0
```

Here's the fiddle > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bcfd/2

**Edit** Could be the order of execution as suggested below, try it with an in (optimised with ids)

```
SELECT location, CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 9, 4) AS int) AS ProcessCode
FROM   dbo.asset 
Where id in(
 select id
 from dbo.asset 
 WHERE  (status NOT IN ('INACTIVE', 'NOT READY', 'LIMITEDUSE'))
 AND (location LIKE '[1-6]-[12]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-_')
)
```

Comment: I think that works because you're only testing with one, good value. There are other, bad values in there that should be removed via the WHERE clause.

Comment: can u give an example of a "bad" value?

Comment: Sure, anything that doesn't fit that regular expresion: ALM00-00-06, 1-5-RMT, 1-0-DEV.

Comment: every data i use works. i would now be seeing which data breaks it - if its all or specific patterns, can u subset the data?

Answer (score 0):

the cast fails before the where, yes. Indeed the cast is failing before the SELECT itself, if i'm not mistaken, right after it looks at the table and determines the shape of the substring under the location column.

You seem to be making a miscalculation as to what the Substring being returned is, because if you say the format indeed is 1-2-100-0800-A, then SUBSTRING(str,9, 4) should return 0800, but it's returning '-1-', which is not an INT.

dissect your statement into smaller ones. i'd look into the result of SUBSTRING first.

hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I'm miscalculating what Substring returns. I think the entire issue is that the cast is happening before the WHERE filter, but I could be wrong. If that's the case, then why does the first query work?